# Hoping Routers / Mac Address / ARP

Tags: router, arp, osi

As a packet travels from a source IP to a destination IP, assuming that it makes hops across many different routers, how does each router know the next MAC address in the sequence.  It is my understanding that for communication in a local network, a computer gets the destination MAC address using the Address Resolution Protocol.  But for the intermediary router hops, how does a frame get the next set of L2 Mac headers without storing (at least briefly) the IP address of the next router?  Is this a separate protocol or something? How does it even know which router (and thus IP in order to get next MAC address?) it should jump to next